# let and const modifier behavior details within ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I was running in a bunch of unexpected behaviour of the `const` modifier within an Angular 2 `*ngFor` statement.

Assuming I have the following base code:

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
    list: string[];
}

@Component({ ... })
class FooComponent() {
    @Input foo: Foo;
    @Input list: string[];
}
```

Using `const` in the following template would be completely fine at compilation time and runtime.

```html
<li *ngFor="const element of list"> ... </li>
```

Now, if we use the SlicePipe, `const` no longer works and the TypeScript compiler is raising an error at the `|` token.

```
<li *ngFor="const element of list | slice:0:3"> ... </li>
                                  ^ unexpected token
<li *ngFor="let element of list | slice:0:3"><!-- completely fine --></li>
```

I was expecting the pipe to be applied on the list, and the only reason I can find for `const` being invalid is that slice is applied on the element, not the list (which is weird no?).

However the fun came when trying to iterate over `Foo.list` using const.

```
<li *ngFor="const element of foo.list"> ... </li>
                                ^ unexpected token
<li *ngFor="let element of foo.list"><!-- completely fine --></li>
```

When should we use `const` then? Why should we use `let` in these situations?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular templates, the use of the let keyword within the *ngFor directive doesn't precisely mirror the JavaScript let semantics. Instead, it's an Angular-specific micro-syntax. Here's why const doesn't work as you might expect:

1. Angular Micro-syntax: As highlighted by [@pkozlowski-opensource](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9209#issuecomment-226298752), what you write inside *ngFor isn't JavaScript or TypeScript but an Angular-specific micro-syntax. Angular doesn't try to replicate the entire JavaScript syntax in templates.
2. Variables in Templates are Properties: As mentioned by [@trotyl](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9209#issuecomment-332383822), all template context "variables" are properties, not variables. This means the distinction between JavaScript let and const semantics doesn't directly apply here. Instead, it's a design choice made by the Angular team.

To sum up, when iterating over lists in Angular templates, you should use let due to the design choices made by the Angular team, which prioritize clarity and prevent potential ambiguities. For me personally, I prefer React and the real JS / ES6 syntax, though.